# Como é possível condicionar ou checar um item em uma listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

Como é possível condicionar ou checar um item em uma listview?

Eu tenho um Array com alguns nomes, eu gostaria de identificar o nome clicado para que eu pudesse fazer uma condição, por exemplo eu cliquei em "Andrew Murray", em seguida, a partir desse item ele vai puxar informações de Andrew Murray em outro Array.

Como é possível fazer isso?

Meu código:

```
// CRIANDO O ARRAY

        final String[] autores =

                {
                        "A W Pink",
                        "A W Tozer",
                        "Abigail Van Buren",
                        "Abraham Kuyper",
                        "Adoniran Judson",
                        "Agostinho",
                        "Alexander Peden",
                        "Allan Redpath",
                        "Alvin Reid",
                        "Andrew Bonar",
                        "Andrew Murray",
                        "Andrew Young"
   };

  ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (

                        // Primeiro Parametro do Array Adpater é o Context

                        getApplicationContext(),

                        // Segundo Parametro do Array Adpater é o Layout

                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        android.R.id.text1,

                        // Terceiro Parametro do Array Adapter é indicar o nome do Array para exibição

                        autores

                );

        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

        // EVENTO DE CLIQUE

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Titulo.this,Autor.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer saber qual item o usuário clicou, basta usar a posição referente ao clique em seu vetor de *strings*. Veja:

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {

    // Toast mostrando qual possição e o autor clicado
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Posição: " + position+" Autor:"+autores[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();

     if("Andrew Murray".equals(autores[position])){
         // se entrar aqui nesta condição, quer dizer que o usuário clicou em
         // Andrew Murray
     }
  }
});
```

Isso já responde sua pergunta, porém pode ser um pouco custoso pois teria que adicionar todos os autores na condição. Para melhorar a solução, você teria que adicionar mais detalhes do seu problema, por exemplo, onde os detalhes de cada autor está localizado, para que seja possível adaptar essa resposta.

Comment: So uma observação para comparar `strings` o método `==` não funciona muito bem (é uma comparação de referência, ou seja, ambos os objetos apontam para o mesmo local de memória), para isto a melhor opção é utilizar o `.equals` (avalia a comparação de valores nos objetos) tipo: `"Andrew Murray".equals(autores[position])`

Comment: Beleza @brow-joe !

Comment: Muito Obrigado, resolveu o problema!
A principio teria que adicionar todos os autores na condição, a única coisa  que poderia melhorar seria utilizando o sqlite.
Valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Para você identificar o item clicado dentro da `listview` você vai precisar utilizar o método `setOnItemClickListener`, nele há um parâmetro inteiro chamado `position`, nele é a posição da lista que foi clicada, basicamente você so vai precisar fazer `autores[position]`

você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String autor = autores[position];
        Toast.makeText(context, "Você Clicou em: " + autor, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Titulo.this,Autor.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

desta forma você ja tem o nome do autor na variável `autor`, com base nisto você ja consegue fazer os tratamentos adequados